# multiple windows audio controllers?

Tags: windows, audio

I have a computer running Windows 10 Home.  In Device Manager, under 'Sound, Video and game controllers', I see the following:

- Magic Sound
- NVIDIA High Definition Audio
- NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)
- Realtek(R) Audio

My questions related to this are:

1. Is it expected that all of these are listed?
2. Is it possible / likely to cause problems to have more than one listed here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Not really, do you have any problems with sound?

In Control Panel or Settings, you can choose the default device/output, and disable ones you may not use, or if everything works leave it as is.

You can also disable devices in Device Manager, but again, if it's not cause problems, leave them as is.